# Having trouble defining variable, Python 3.9, Spyder IDE

Tags: python, variables

`longitude[:] = lon`

Code analysis says longitude variable not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
longitude = lon
```

but make sure `lon` has been defined first.

`longitude[:]` can only be used when `longitude` is previously assigned. Even then it is not a great way to define or reassign variables.

If you are trying to copy `lon` to `longitude` here is an example:

```
lon = [1,2,3]
longitude = lon[:] 
print(lon)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Here you can use `[:]` to ensure you create an entirely new list. Maybe this is where the confusion came from.